# JQuery show/hide when hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have three links, Cat, Dog, Snakes. When I hover over each, the content relating to each link should change.

So if i hover over cat, then cat content will appear, if i hover over dog the cat content will smoothly disappear and the dog content will appear... and so on.

```
Links are: Dog   Cat  Snake
```

```
<div>
  <span style="display:none;"> Cat Content</span>
  <span style="display:none;"> Dog Content</span>
  <span style="display:none;"> Snake Content</span>    
</div>
```

How do I get this to be full blown working, with some smooth fading?

Comment: I would use jquery tabs :) its much better, and use the mouse over option, http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#mouseover demo link, I know it might not be the right thing for you but hey you can use it, and also have free themes :)

Comment: no this way, i dont like

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
('.cat').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).hide();
  }
);
```

It's the same for the others.

For the smooth fade in you can use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

Comment: is there anyway you can show an example on http://jsfiddle.net, it will really help.

Answer (score 10):

jquery:

```
$('div.animalcontent').hide();
$('div').hide();
$('p.animal').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('div.animalcontent').fadeOut();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'content').fadeIn();
});
```

html:

```
<p class='animal' id='dog'>dog url</p><div id='dogcontent' class='animalcontent'>Doggiecontent!</div>
<p class='animal' id='cat'>cat url</p><div id='catcontent' class='animalcontent'>Pussiecontent!</div>
<p class='animal' id='snake'>snake url</p><div id='snakecontent'class='animalcontent'>Snakecontent!</div>
```

-edit-

yeah sure, [here you go -- JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeaWm/)

Comment: hey this is perfect...thanks a lot...i think i can build on this..now i see visually how you did it.

Comment: Good to hear! Glad I could be of help. It it works out, please accept this answer.

Comment: Hey i need 1 more help. i wanted it to: when the mouse is not on any of them, none of the content show up...seems as if when the mouse leave the previous link, that previous link content still shows as visible.

Answer (score 7):

I hope my script help you.

```
<i class="mostrar-producto">mostrar...</i>
<div class="producto" style="display:none;position: absolute;">Producto</div>
```

**My script**

```
<script>
$(".mostrar-producto").mouseover(function(){
     $(".producto").fadeIn();
 });

 $(".mostrar-producto").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".producto").fadeOut();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: To avoid queuing up many animations you can add stop() before fadeOut or fadeIn like `$(".producto").stop().fadeIn();`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery, you just need to attach to some specific events and some pre defined animations:

```
$('#cat').hover(function()
{
     // Mouse Over Callback
}, function()
{ 
     // Mouse Leave callback
});
```

Then, to do the animation, you simply need to call the fadeOut / fadeIn animations:

```
$('#dog').fadeOut(750 /* Animation Time */, function()
{
    // animation complete callback
     $('#cat').fadeIn(750);
});
```

Combining the two together, you would simply insert the animations in the hover callbacks (something like so, use this as a reference point):

```
$('#cat').hover(function()
{
     if($('#dog').is(':visible'))
        $('#dog').fadeOut(750 /* Animation Time */, function()
     {
        // animation complete callback
         $('#cat').fadeIn(750);
     });
}, function()
{ 
     // Mouse Leave callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also works.

```js
$(".circle").hover(function() {$(this).hide(200).show(200);});
```

```css
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:black;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">hover me</div>
```