# HTML - Docked element

Tags: html, css, dock

I have designed a simple website. The only thing left is to make a small box on the left. But I want to be always visible even when I scroll down. It's use will be something like a small ad. ![floating box][1]

Can you post an example or two? what css is needed for this? (if it's needed)

unfortunately I can't post any images because of I am a new user (I am not allowed to.. and this kinda frustrating)

But I will post an image as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply `position: fixed` to this box.

> Fixed Positioning
>
> An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser
>   window.
>
> It will not move even if the window is scrolled.

Here's a sample: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed

You can read more about CSS positioning here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

---

Here's a jsFiddle that I baked for your that shows how you can get this working: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/8ub7s/2/

You can see that even when you scroll, the title is still visible and if you hover it, the ad box will show. Just adapt the CSS to your needs as you want it floated to the left. :)

Comment: thank you I will check it out and let you know if any problem occurs. 
Do you know by any chance how I can make this box also to auto-hide? Only its title will be visible and then by moving the mouse over the whole box will revealed.. :) thank you again!

Comment: Let's say the box is inside a `<div id="myBox" style="display:none">My ad here!</div>`. Then it starts with `display:none`(invisible). Now you can add a bit of jQuery code to make it appear on mouse hover and disappear when the mouse moves out using code like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5404862/114029 Just replace `$('.cat').hover` with `$("#myBox").hover`.

Comment: I tried to apply this to a table. The reason it's because I have already my page designed.. So adding a new element it's very difficult. I don't even know where to place it without affecting the rest contents. So I need a way to place a new table (so I can have my little Ad box - with a title and a small image in a cell) without affecting anything else and of course with the fixed-position feature. Does anyone has facebook to help on this online?

Comment: You can post a new question with some of your HTML code so that we can help you...