# Jquery for active state + ID on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the example from here:
[Jquery Show/Hide when Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404775/jquery-show-hide-when-hover/).
It's working great for showing the div content when the user hovers over a link.  And only shows the next div content when the next link is hovered over.

The problem is I also want to create an active state for that link on mouseover and fade it out when there is a new mouseover.

It's difficult for me because the active state is controlled by an ID, not a class.  Is there a way to do this?

Right now I'm using:

```
 $('div.animalcontent').hide();
 $('div').hide();
 $('a.animal').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('div.animalcontent').fadeOut();
 $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'content').fadeIn();
 });
```

And this is what my links look like:

```
<a href="dogcontent" class='animal' id='dog'>Dog</a>
<a href="catcontent" class='animal' id='cat'>Dog</a>
<a href="snakecontent" class='animal' id='snake'>Dog</a>
```

Controls these divs:

```
<div id='dogcontent' class='animalcontent'>Some dog content</div>
<div id='catcontent' class='animalcontent'>Some cat content</div>
<div id='snakecontent' class='animalcontent'>Some snake content</div>
```

The only CSS that works for highlighting the Active state is using:

```
a#dog:active
a#cat:active
a#snake:active
```

The inclusion of the different ID's is over my head.

Comment: Your html looks incomplete.

Comment: Thank you @TravisJ I added the rest of the html.

Answer (score 1):

For active states I use a class.

```
 $('div.animalcontent').hide();
 $('div').hide();
 $('a.animal').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div.animalcontent').fadeOut();
 $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'content').fadeIn();
 });
```

And in the CSS you should use the class selector:

```
a#dog.active{}
a#cat.active{}
a#snake.active{}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me.  I can control the hover state using: a.animal:hover, but the active state is not registering using a.animal:active.  Also, I need the active state to persist until the next mouseover.  thank you.