# After hovering on images at the top of a webpage I want to specific div and hide other div based on the image hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

First, all three line of text will visible. Those are in different div. When I hover on IMAGE 1, only the first div should visible and other two should be hidden.

Like this, If I hover on IMAGE 3, only the third div text or 3rd line should visible and other line should hide.

Can you please sugget me how to achive that? Or can you give me a working example or code please? I tried using different way but failed.

Please check the html code in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/mdykabir/ex67pfs1/2/

```
    <div class="images">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.png">
</div>

<div class="infoArea">
    <div id="infOne">
        Show this div if hover on image 1.
    </div>

    <div id="infTwo">
        Show this div if hover on image 2.
    </div>

    <div id="infThree">
        Show this div if hover on image 3.
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add an event handler for `mouseover`/`mouseout` on the images, like this, and then toggle a class which hides/shows the div

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images > img');
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.infoArea > div');
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

    (function(i){
      images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        document.querySelector('.infoArea').classList.toggle('hide');
        divs[i].classList.toggle('show');
        
      })
      images[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        document.querySelector('.infoArea').classList.toggle('hide');
        divs[i].classList.toggle('show');
      })
    })(i);

  }  
})
```

```css
.infoArea.hide div {
  display: none;
}
.infoArea > div.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.png">
</div>

<div class="infoArea">
    <div id="infOne">
        Show this div if hover on image 1.
    </div>

    <div id="infTwo">
        Show this div if hover on image 2.
    </div>

    <div id="infThree">
        Show this div if hover on image 3.
    </div>
<div>
```

---

With a small markup change you don't even need script, just CSS hover

```css
.images {
  display: inline-block;
}
.images:hover ~ .infoArea > div {
  display: none;
}
.images.imgOne:hover ~ .infoArea #infOne,
.images.imgTwo:hover ~ .infoArea #infTwo,
.images.imgThree:hover ~ .infoArea #infThree {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="images imgOne">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1.png">
</div>
<div class="images imgTwo">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2.png">
</div>
<div class="images imgThree">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.png">
</div>

<div class="infoArea">
    <div id="infOne">
        Show this div if hover on image 1.
    </div>

    <div id="infTwo">
        Show this div if hover on image 2.
    </div>

    <div id="infThree">
        Show this div if hover on image 3.
    </div>
<div>
```

---

Based on a comment, here is a sample how to toggle on click, with persistent result

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images > img');
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.infoArea > div');
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

    (function(i,old){
      images[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        old = document.querySelector('.infoArea .show');
        if (old) {
          old.classList.toggle('show');
        }
        if (old != divs[i]) {
          divs[i].classList.toggle('show');
        }        
      })
    })(i);

  }  
})
```

```css
.infoArea div {
  display: none;
}
.infoArea > div.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2.png">
    <img src="http://www.mykabir.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.png">
</div>

<div class="infoArea">
    <div id="infOne">
        Show this div if hover on image 1.
    </div>

    <div id="infTwo">
        Show this div if hover on image 2.
    </div>

    <div id="infThree">
        Show this div if hover on image 3.
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: At `css` version, note description of requirement at OP _"First, all three line of text will visible."_

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, missed that ... updated ... updated script too :)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your nice codes and help. It works fine.

Comment: Also, can you help me in another way. For example, suppose I want to click on the image and after that their relative div will visible till I click again on another image.

Comment: @MdYasinKabir Added a 3:rd sample showing one way to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) DOM events.

Here's a minimal example that accomplishes what you want with your example:

```js
function showOnHover(args) {
  var trigger = args.trigger;
  var target = args.target;
  
  trigger.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
   target.style.display = 'block';
  })
  
  trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
   target.style.display = 'none';
  })
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images img');
var toShow = document.querySelectorAll('.infoArea div');
var triggersAndTargets = Array.prototype.map.call(images, function (img, i) {
return { trigger: img, target: toShow[i] };
});

triggersAndTargets.forEach(showOnHover);
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ex67pfs1/16/

And for an ES2015 version: https://jsfiddle.net/ex67pfs1/18/

Checkout [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404775/jquery-show-hide-when-hover) for a jQuery solution.

Comment: This is a pretty cool solution, just dropping by to say that:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do this in plain JS, I would stay away from CSS solutions if you target non sibling elements. If you target the element or a sibling, then do it with CSS, otherwise, there is now ay around JS.
This JS code can be done bit better, I will pack all into one function, but adding the listeners is a must.

```
var pic1 = document.getElementById('first');
var pic2 = document.getElementById('sec');
var pic3 = document.getElementById('thi');

pic1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
var div1 = document.getElementById('infOne');
div1.style.opacity=1;

});

pic1.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
var div1 = document.getElementById('infOne');
div1.style.opacity=0;

});
```

Check it out here, I changed some css as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/ex67pfs1/15/

Comment: Well, the hover pseudo is ok for the direct event target or the siblings, but when you want to target elements outside the "scope", JS is a must.

Comment: True, I will change that in the reply to clarify, of course targeting the event target and siblings should be done with css:-)